# Unable to set a static ip for Xubuntu system

Tags: networking, xubuntu

I want to set static IP on my machine.
This is what I have now:

```
root@jim-VirtualBox:~# ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:81:10:5c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:783 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:71283 (71.2 KB)  TX bytes:19709 (19.7 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:14:64:9d  
          inet addr:192.168.99.101  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3461:cced:7c8e:8911/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:74 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24237 (24.2 KB)  TX bytes:10606 (10.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:10194 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:10194 (10.1 KB)

root@jim-VirtualBox:~
```

I have/edited my interfaces file as below:

```
root@jim-VirtualBox:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static 
address 192.168.1.11
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.1.1

root@jim-VirtualBox:~#
```

Now if I do ifconfig, I still get 192.168.1.6 and not .11(last bit)

```
root@jim-VirtualBox:~# ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:81:10:5c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:811 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:75130 (75.1 KB)  TX bytes:22702 (22.7 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:14:64:9d  
          inet addr:192.168.99.101  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3461:cced:7c8e:8911/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:74 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24237 (24.2 KB)  TX bytes:10606 (10.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:10194 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:10194 (10.1 KB)

root@jim-VirtualBox:~#
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Yes I did `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Have you tried `ifdown enp0s3 && ifup enp0s3`? Bringing the interface down and back up again?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer vim instead of cat. Here's how I set static IPs on the daily:

Get and install vim (if needed):

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Open to edit the network interfaces file:

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Make changes to the network interfaces file, to appear as so: I used 192.168.10.10 as the static IP in the example.

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.10.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255
    gateway 192.168.10.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.10.111
```

Then restart the service as you normally do or as I would do:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0
```

wait

```
sudo ifup enp2s0
```

Now check your ifconfig and you should now see the static IP

```
ifconfig
```

Good luck and Enjoy!

If that doesn't work, try shutting all network interfaces off and back on with `sudo ifdown -a` and `sudo ifup -a`

Comment: Many Thanks for that. It did worked but I am now not connected to internet and I cannot install any package.
Initially my IP was 192.168.1.11 then it got changed to
192.168.1.6  and after following instructions given by you I got it set to 192.168.1.11(Initial). Not sure why I lost my access to internet?

Comment: Have a look here
root@jim-VirtualBox:~# ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
Now ssh to another was already established so why it says ssh keys not found?? Any security breach on my system ??

root@jim-VirtualBox:~# ssh 192.168.1.7
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:MgmT0E0bgIhdNiFs9TEhucnOO9WkoozhPptXRttDEKw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.7' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@192.168.1.7's password:

Comment: The current RedHat time is 2016-05-30 22:32:37 +1000

[root@agent2 ~]#

Comment: I added line nameserver 192.168.1.1(router IP) to /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Not sure if the above is going to be a permanent solution as it says in that file that the changes would be overwritten...

Comment: I think issue is resolved I update base file  in /etc/resolv/resolv.conf/.d/base to
nameserver 192.168.1.1

Where 192.168.1.1 is the router IP and is working fine !

I would post results after reboot and see if its really working.